# What do you call third order derivative matrix and what does it geometrically signify?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, jacobian, hessian-matrix, gradient-flows

The first-order derivatives matrix is known as Jacobian, gives the gradient of the graph.
Similarly, the second-order derivatives matrix is Hessian, which gives the curvature of the plot.
What next? i.e., is there a third-order derivative matrix? If yes, what does it denote?

Comment: Hint : please take a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ and another one $g:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ and think what of the objects you mentioned is a matrix and what is just a vector. Then we turn to the third derivative. Also : does $g$ have a Hessian matrix ?

Comment: Let's assume that g is indeed n-differentiable. Then, what will the third derivative of the g-curve denote?

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j\partial x_l\partial x_k}$ . Doesn't look like a matrix to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the Taylor series expansion is
\begin{align*}
f(\mathbb{x}) = f(\mathbb{z}) + \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - z_i)f_{i}(\mathbb{z})} + \frac{1}{2}\color{orange}{\sum_{i,j} (x_i - z_i)(x_j-z_j)f_{ij}(\mathbb{z})} + \frac{1}{6}\color{greeN}{\sum_{ijk}(x_i-z_i)(x_j-z_j)(x_k-z_k)f_{ijk}(\mathbb{z})} + \cdots
\end{align*}
where $f_i(\mathbb{z}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}f(\mathbb{z})$, $f_{ij}(\mathbb{z}) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z_i\partial z_j}f(\mathbb{z})$, and so on. We normally represent the blue expression as
\begin{align*}
(\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{z})^\intercal [\nabla f(\mathbb{z})]
\end{align*}
and the orange expression as
\begin{align*}
(\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{z})^\intercal [\nabla^2f(\mathbb{z})](\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{z})
\end{align*}
here, $\nabla f(\mathbb{z})$ and $\nabla^2 f(\mathbb{z})$ denote the gradients and Hessians, respectively. If we could, we wish to represent the green portion in a similar manner, perhaps
\begin{align*}
(\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{z})^\intercal \underset{(\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{z})^\dagger}{[\nabla^3f(\mathbb{z})]}(\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{z})
\end{align*}
in which case, we see the matrix of third derivatives appear. Note that we haven't defined how to conduct this 3D matrix multiplication, and I'm simply using the above notation to give you the idea that $(\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{z})$ must be utilized thrice (i.e. 3rd-power products). The formal definition leads to the [n-mode product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2284073/117529).

Comment: Can you also lead me to the physical interpretation of it? In geometry, what this could possibly represent?